# How do I install unauthorized software?

Tags: installation, software-center

I am trying to install software from the Ubuntu Software Center and keep getting the error saying that it is unauthorized software. I have all the check marks in place for downloading in System/software sources. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Enable *Universe* and *Multiverse* repos in your sources.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Edit this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://us.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

To look like this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then just run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I am sorry but those lines are not present in my system.